create dockerfile to expose electron application on local port
For an electron application I want to create a docker file to expose this application on a local port
See docker file:
FROM node:20
RUN apt-get update \
&& apt-get install libx11-xcb1 libxcb-dri3-0 libxtst6 libnss3 libatk-bridge2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libxss1 \
libasound2 libdrm2 libgbm1 libglvnd-dev dbus nano xauth  \
-yq --no-install-suggests --no-install-recommends   \
&& apt-get clean \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN chown -R node /app
RUN pwd
RUN ls -l
USER node
RUN npm install 
## change dir to install application
WORKDIR bot-app
RUN pwd 
RUN npm install 
RUN npx electron-rebuild
RUN ls -l

USER root
  RUN chown root /app/bot-app/node_modules/electron/dist/chrome-sandbox
  RUN chmod 4755 /app/bot-app/node_modules/electron/dist/chrome-sandbox
EXPOSE 8085
USER node
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
##CMD ["bash"]

The creation of the docker image with the following command works fine:
docker build -t matrix-bot-app --no-cache=true .

But as soon as I create a docker container with :
docker run -it --name=matrix-bot-container -p 8085:8085 matrix-bot-app:latest

The following error message will be displayed: 

> bot-app@1.0.0 start
> electron .

Failed to move to new namespace: PID namespaces supported, Network namespace supported, but failed: errno = Operation not permitted
[28:1018/131723.599820:FATAL:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(201)] Check failed: . : Invalid argument (22)

Any idea ???
Many thanks in advance !

Docker isn't necessarily a great packaging format for running desktop GUI applications: since it's at its core an isolation system, it has trouble seeing the display system, and the "standard" setup for it is complex and somewhat Linux-specific (Can you run GUI applications in a Linux Docker container?).  That's a little secondary to an error about PID namespaces, but that also suggests Electron is trying to do something complicated that's not allowed in a container.
